# Main difference between Lean UX and Agile

Tags: lean-ux, agile

Which is(are) the main difference(s) between Lean UX and the Agile approach?

Comment: You can check the Project Management channel on Stack Exchange. Agile methods are thoroughly discussed over there.

Comment: It is hard to compare the two in the context of UXSE unless you are trying to compare specific activities when it comes to the execution of the design (separate to the other activities). But the question feels a little bit broad to cover well so perhaps consider if you want to focus on a particular aspect or what you want to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but Lean UX is a practice when UX goes agile. So technically there are no reasonable differences. However, some experts argue that UXD process is basically agile.

Answer (score 0):

as your question is upon the difference between two, so from my perspective there is no big difference.As both help in product development with high ROI.
Lean UX & agile UX are in fact put forward based on Lean Software Development & Agile Software Development. Lean UX, which makes “user experience” as its core, focuses more on the matching degree of product and market. Both of them have their pros and cons but they are equally important in product design.
Hope you got your answer but if you still have any query related to this please comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general senses, not only UX or IT, **Lean** designates ongoing repetative methods of testing and trying product before implementation. 
**Agile** is more related to project communication and it designates, flexible, adaptive way project teams collaborate with each other and with client.